# nodejs deb package seems to miss npm

Tags: debian, node.js, npm

I did on Debian testing `sudo apt install nodejs` but I'm missing `npm`.

```
$ node -v
v8.11.2
$ npm -v
bash: npm: command not found
```

What did I miss?

Comment: should I do [this](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm` turned out to [involve too much work to maintain properly](https://bugs.debian.org/857986) (with security support etc.) in Debian 9, given the current level of maintainer involvement, so it was removed from the release and [isn’t available](https://tracker.debian.org/npm) from the “stable” Debian repositories.

To install NPM you should follow [the upstream instructions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions), which will configure your system to use their repository:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

This will install Node.js 8.x; if you need 10.x you can replace the “8” above with “10”.

Comment: pnpm sound actually good `
curl -L https://unpkg.com/@pnpm/self-installer | sudo node`

Comment: hm, this will still install the -dfsg debian version without npm :-(

Comment: @dothebart I just checked, and on a default Debian setup, the instructions above install the Node.js-hosted version with `npm` (`apt policy` shows it as the candidate version). You might want to ask a new question explaining your problem: describe the steps you followed to try to install `nodejs`, and most importantly, include the output of `apt policy nodejs`.

Comment: my problem was that the script will terminate if there are apt-errors from other repos, and thus the nodesource repo wasn't added in first place.

Answer (score 0):

To Install NodeJS execute following three steps

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```